# How do I get user's email from twitter authentication

Tags: asp.net, twitter, twitter-oauth

We have an ASP.NET application where we need user's email in order to further send them transactional email. We have added Twitter Signup but not getting email address along with access_token.

We have checked twitter documentation and their FAQs for the same but have had no luck so far. The FAQ says that we need to ask for user's email in as a distinct act:

[image]

recently I came to a website http://medium.com which asks for email while authentication in it's scope, please refer to the image below:

[image]

I'm not sure how do I add email scope to my twitter application. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to get user's email address from twitter.

This can be made possible by filling out a form to request [elevated permissions](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials):

1. Go to https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform
2. Select "I need access to special permissions"
3. Enter Application Name and ID. These can be obtained via
   https://apps.twitter.com/ -- the application ID is the numeric part
   in the browser's address bar after you click your app.
4. Permissions Request: "Email address" Submit & wait for response