# How to get email address from twitter

Tags: angularjs, twitter, ionic-framework

The **twitter** login is used by my app using `ionic framework`, and i want to get email address from twitter, i have requested twitter and app is now able  to get email address.

But somehow the  code below is not able to get email address.

For this i have created new function named `getTwitterProfileManual` but still it is not working.

I have also read document provided by twitter at [Doc](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials) and as suggested i am also passing `include_email` params as request query. But still response do not have email address in it.

```
serviceModule.factory('TwitterService', function ($cordovaOauth, $cordovaOauthUtility, $http, $resource, $q, AUTH_ID)
{

    var twitterKey = "STORAGE.TWITTER.KEY";
    var clientId = AUTH_ID.TWITTER_APP_ID;
    var clientSecret = AUTH_ID.TWITTER_APP_SEC;

    function storeUserToken(data)
    {
        window.localStorage.setItem(twitterKey, JSON.stringify(data));
    }

    function getStoredToken()
    {
        return window.localStorage.getItem(twitterKey);
    }

    function createTwitterSignature(method, url, params)
    {
        if (!params) {
            params = {};
        }
        var token = angular.fromJson(getStoredToken());

        var oauthObject = {
            oauth_consumer_key: clientId,
            oauth_nonce: $cordovaOauthUtility.createNonce(10),
            oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1",
            oauth_token: token.oauth_token,
            oauth_timestamp: Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000.0),
            oauth_version: "1.0"
        };
        console.log(JSON.stringify(oauthObject));
        var signatureObj = $cordovaOauthUtility.createSignature(method, url, oauthObject, params, clientSecret, token.oauth_token_secret);
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = signatureObj.authorization_header;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(signatureObj.authorization_header));
    }

    return {
        initialize: function ()
        {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var token = getStoredToken();

            if (token !== null)
            {
                deferred.resolve(true);
            }
            else
            {
                $cordovaOauth.twitter(clientId, clientSecret).then(function (result)
                {
                    storeUserToken(result);
                    deferred.resolve(true);
                }, function (error)
                {
                    deferred.reject(false);
                });
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        isAuthenticated: function ()
        {
            return getStoredToken() !== null;
        },
        getHomeTimeline: function ()
        {
            var home_tl_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json';
            createTwitterSignature('GET', home_tl_url);
            return $resource(home_tl_url).query();
        },
        getTwitterProfile: function ()
        {
            var tl_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json';
            createTwitterSignature('GET', tl_url);
            return $resource(tl_url, {'include_email': true}).query();
        },
        getTwitterProfileManual: function () {

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var token = angular.fromJson(getStoredToken());

            createTwitterSignature('GET', 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json');

            //            $http.get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json")

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json",
                params : { 'include_email': true }
            }).success(function (result)
            {
                console.log(result);
                alert('USER TIMELINE: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
                deferred.resolve(result);
            }).error(function (error)
            {
                alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
                deferred.reject(false);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        storeUserToken: storeUserToken,
        getStoredToken: getStoredToken,
        createTwitterSignature: createTwitterSignature
    };
});
```

Does anyone came across such problem and solved it, if so please provide some hint.

Comment: anyone with any idea?

Comment: what is the process you followed to  get twitter email  authentication?

Comment: @Webruster Thank you for being first to comment, all i did was just send request to twitter at https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform  and checked i  need access to special permissions checkbox and on next day my app was allowed to get email address

Comment: you mean to say same like  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33383320/how-do-i-get-users-email-from-twitter-authentication/33385082#33385082) process ?

Comment: @Webruster   Yeah right.

Comment: a last question , did you test this with already authenticated user ? or a New user?

Comment: Yes i did tested it via twitter APi signature and from curl call i could able to see email address.

Comment: My question is are you  trying to get the Email Address of an user who is already been authenticated before sending this email request prior to ur requesting.

Comment: @Webruster, Yes i am. but i have also tried with new one after getting authorize for email access.

Comment: in your `'include_email': true`, try to use boolean in quotation `'include_email': 'true'` .If you leave the boolean as a boolean and not a string, the email request will be ignored.

Comment: No luck, got error,  "could not authenticate"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102330/discussion-between-webruster-and-dipesh-parmar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After days of working i finally made it working.

Below is the code for anyone who will face such issue.

**Code :**

```
serviceModule.factory('$twitterHelpers', ['$q', '$http', function ($q, $http) {

    function createSignature(method, endPoint, headerParameters, bodyParameters, secretKey, tokenSecret) {
        if (typeof jsSHA !== "undefined") {
            var headerAndBodyParameters = angular.copy(headerParameters);
            var bodyParameterKeys = Object.keys(bodyParameters);
            for (var i = 0; i < bodyParameterKeys.length; i++) {
                headerAndBodyParameters[bodyParameterKeys[i]] = escapeSpecialCharacters(bodyParameters[bodyParameterKeys[i]]);
            }
            var signatureBaseString = method + "&" + encodeURIComponent(endPoint) + "&";
            var headerAndBodyParameterKeys = (Object.keys(headerAndBodyParameters)).sort();
            for (i = 0; i < headerAndBodyParameterKeys.length; i++) {
                if (i == headerAndBodyParameterKeys.length - 1) {
                    signatureBaseString += encodeURIComponent(headerAndBodyParameterKeys[i] + "=" + headerAndBodyParameters[headerAndBodyParameterKeys[i]]);
                } else {
                    signatureBaseString += encodeURIComponent(headerAndBodyParameterKeys[i] + "=" + headerAndBodyParameters[headerAndBodyParameterKeys[i]] + "&");
                }
            }
            var oauthSignatureObject = new jsSHA(signatureBaseString, "TEXT");

            var encodedTokenSecret = '';
            if (tokenSecret) {
                encodedTokenSecret = encodeURIComponent(tokenSecret);
            }

            headerParameters.oauth_signature = encodeURIComponent(oauthSignatureObject.getHMAC(encodeURIComponent(secretKey) + "&" + encodedTokenSecret, "TEXT", "SHA-1", "B64"));
            var headerParameterKeys = Object.keys(headerParameters);
            var authorizationHeader = 'OAuth ';
            for (i = 0; i < headerParameterKeys.length; i++) {
                if (i == headerParameterKeys.length - 1) {
                    authorizationHeader += headerParameterKeys[i] + '="' + headerParameters[headerParameterKeys[i]] + '"';
                } else {
                    authorizationHeader += headerParameterKeys[i] + '="' + headerParameters[headerParameterKeys[i]] + '",';
                }
            }
            return {signature_base_string: signatureBaseString, authorization_header: authorizationHeader, signature: headerParameters.oauth_signature};
        } else {
            return "Missing jsSHA JavaScript library";
        }
    }

    function createNonce(length) {
        var text = "";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        }
        return text;
    }

    function escapeSpecialCharacters(string) {
        var tmp = encodeURIComponent(string);
        tmp = tmp.replace(/\!/g, "%21");
        tmp = tmp.replace(/\'/g, "%27");
        tmp = tmp.replace(/\(/g, "%28");
        tmp = tmp.replace(/\)/g, "%29");
        tmp = tmp.replace(/\*/g, "%2A");
        return tmp;
    }

    function transformRequest(obj) {
        var str = [];
        for (var p in obj)
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + escapeSpecialCharacters(obj[p]));
        console.log(str.join('&'));
        return str.join('&');
    }

    return {
        createTwitterSignature: function (method, url, bodyParameters, clientId, clientSecret, token) {
            var oauthObject = {
                oauth_consumer_key: clientId,
                oauth_nonce: createNonce(10),
                oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1",
                oauth_token: token.oauth_token,
                oauth_timestamp: Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000.0),
                oauth_version: "1.0"
            };
            var signatureObj = createSignature(method, url, oauthObject, bodyParameters, clientSecret, token.oauth_token_secret);
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = signatureObj.authorization_header;
            return signatureObj;
        },
        transformRequest: transformRequest
    };
}]);

serviceModule.factory('TwitterService', function ($cordovaOauth, $cordovaOauthUtility, $http, $resource, $q, AUTH_ID, $twitterHelpers)
{

    var twitterKey = "STORAGE.TWITTER.KEY";
    var clientId = AUTH_ID.TWITTER_APP_ID;
    var clientSecret = AUTH_ID.TWITTER_APP_SEC;

    function storeUserToken(data)
    {
        window.localStorage.setItem(twitterKey, JSON.stringify(data));
    }

    function getStoredToken()
    {
        return window.localStorage.getItem(twitterKey);
    }

    return {
        initialize: function ()
        {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var token = getStoredToken();

            if (token !== null)
            {
                deferred.resolve(true);
            }
            else
            {
                $cordovaOauth.twitter(clientId, clientSecret).then(function (result)
                {
                    storeUserToken(result);
                    deferred.resolve(true);
                }, function (error)
                {
                    deferred.reject(false);
                });
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        isAuthenticated: function ()
        {
            return getStoredToken() !== null;
        },
        getHomeTimeline: function ()
        {
            var home_tl_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json';
            createTwitterSignature('GET', home_tl_url);
            return $resource(home_tl_url).query();
        },
        getTwitterProfileManual: function () {

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var token = angular.fromJson(getStoredToken());

            $twitterHelpers.createTwitterSignature('GET', 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json', { 'include_email' : 'true' }, clientId, clientSecret, token);

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json",
                params: {'include_email': 'true'},
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success(function (result)
            {
                console.log(result);
                alert('USER TIMELINE: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
                deferred.resolve(result);
            }).error(function (error)
            {
                alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
                deferred.reject(false);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        storeUserToken: storeUserToken,
        getStoredToken: getStoredToken
    };
});
```

From the above code use `getTwitterProfileManual` this function to get email address in twitter user object response.

**Note :** To get email address your twitter app must be whitelisted to have access to user email address.